# Getting attribute error: 'map' object has no attribute 'sort'

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, iterable

I am trying to sort array in increasing order. But getting the following error for the code:

```
a = []
a = map(int, input().split(' '))
a.sort()
print(a)
```

Error:

> AttributeError: 'map' object has no attribute 'sort'

Comment: This is not related to the question, but `split()` (i.e. without arguments) is a better choice than  `split(' ')`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In python 3 `map` doesn't return a list. Instead, it returns an iterator object and since `sort` is an attribute of `list` object, you're getting an attribute error.

If you want to sort the result in-place, you need to convert it to list first (which is not recommended).

```
a = list(map(int, input().split(' ')))
a.sort()
```

However, as a better approach, you could use `sorted` function which accepts an iterable and return a sorted list and then reassign the result to the original name (is recommended):

```
a = sorted(map(int, input().split(' ')))
```